# How can i pass angularjs variable to laravel name route?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I have a date picker and i want to get that that and pass to laravel route. how can i do that? 
My blade file:

```
<div class="form-inline">
               <label>Date:</label>
                <input class="form-control datePicker" type="text" name="date" id="date" ng-model="date">

 <a target="_blank" href="{{route('my-report'[@{{date}}])}}">PDF</a>
            </div>
```

my route:

```
 Route::get('my/report/{date}','MyController@geteport')->name('my-report');
```

it it not working!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: syntex error!  I think this not the right way to work wirh name route.

Comment: the double curly braces is not necessary before @date you can directly use the $date there.

Comment: the 'date' is ng-model value not php variable!

Comment: my friend @Fawel what do you want with this code.? the php code runs first and then the angular js code will run so u cannot get from php file by running angular code. i think you understand this.

Comment: I think you did not understand my quest well. when User will select date then click on button to get report of that date wise. i need to pass the date to the name route. i can do this using href='my/report/'@{{date}}. But i want to use name route function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162312/discussion-between-dhaval-purohit-and-fawel).